# Son of Suckerfish Menu problem IE6

Tags: html, css, suckerfish

My menu dropdowns are 'hiding' behind content that appear below the dropdowns. The menu is working fine in Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE8, but not in IE6.

An example of this is on this page - http://marketplace.prettypollution.com/news-events , if you hover over 'Contact Us' in the top menu it is hidden behind the below content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'position: relative;' on the divs below the dropdown menu's were causing the problems (I dont know why though?). I removed them from the divs below and added them to other elements of the site (eg the right div form now has a position of relative rather than the div itself). It all seems to be working ok now.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for not deleting this question. Hopefully IE6 will be dead forever, but that never seems to happen :)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the z-index of both the content and the suckerfish, with the suckerfish having the higher value.